# Problem with moving file and saving file data blank

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, upload

I have some problem here..

I use upload from on index.php and i use jquery (ajax) to save any information to mysql. I have 3 file index.php, savedata.php, jsSave.js

But when i use $_REQUEST file from savedata.php and result is blank response also in mysql table, i replace $_REQUEST and use $_FILES and have same result.

What i already try and use is code like below...

Index.php

```
        <form class="myform" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" name="myform" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:350px;">

                            <li>
                            <label>Item Picture</label>
                            <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                                <span>Choose Image..</span>
                                <input type="file" name="cItemPicture" class="cItemPicture" id="cItemPicture"/>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="cPic" id="cPic"/>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img border="0" src="images/loading_transparent.gif" width="20" height="20" id="imgLoad">
                        &nbsp<button class="button_blue" id="butTblSave" type="submit" style="width: 81px; height: 33px">SAVE</button>
                        </li>
```

and for savedata.php file script is

```
    <?php 
   if($_REQUEST)
{
    ***$cItemPicture=$_FILES["cItemPicture"]["name"];***

    $sql="INSERT INTO tblData(item_image) VALUES ('$cItemPicture')";

    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('Cannot Connect To SQL Server, Please contact your administrator');
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cItemPicture"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["cItemPicture"]["name"]);
}
?>
```

last file which work as AJAX using jQuery file is jsSave.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imgLoad').hide();
    $('#msgConfirm').hide();
    $('#tblAvailabilityResult').hide();
});

$(function() {  
  $("#butTblSave").click(function() {  
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'saveData.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),

            beforeSend: function() {
                $("imgLoad").show();
            },

            complete: function() {
                $("imgLoad").hide();
            },        

            cache: false,

            success: function () {

                $("#cItemPicture").val('');

                $('#imgLoad').hide();
                $('#butTblSave').attr("disabled", false);

                $('#msgConfirm').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
                $("#msgConfirm").html(' Add New Item Success.');

            }

        });
        return false;
    }

  });  
});
```

Do i miss something? when press SAVE button ajax reponse blank and saved data into mysql item_image also blank, also and no file moved into upload folder.

Any idea for this problem? Many thanks about this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try preventing the default submission of the form.
Because the form is submitting to SELF (index.php)

```
$("#butTblSave").click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault();
...
```

Comment: I mean, how in savedata.php can get file upload value? using $_FILES["cItemPicture"]["name"]; I try use $_REQUEST and still nothing happen